# Add Iterations to Azure DevOps via script

Tags: azure-devops

We have quite a number of Iterations to be added to Azure DevOps that is tedious if done manually.

I'm trying to find a way to bulk insert the Iterations via command-line script.
So far not finding info whether this is even possible and if possible how.

The only way that I'm aware of is via this Azure DevOps REST API:
( POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0 )

Would appreciate any tip or suggestion on this issue.

Comment: Can Azure cli meet your needs?Not get your response for this issue. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/index?view=azure-devops) to achieve this. You can add iteration paths to a project using [az boards iteration project create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/iteration/project?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-boards-iteration-project-create).

```
az boards iteration project create --name
                                   [--finish-date]
                                   [--path]
                                   [--project]
                                   [--start-date]
```

- name: Required. Enter the name of the iteration path.
- finish-date: Optional. Finish date of the iteration. Example:
  "2019-06-21".
- path: Optional. Absolute path of an iteration. Example:
  \ProjectName\Iteration\IterationName. When not specified, adds an
  iteration at the root level.
- project: Optional. Name or ID of the project. Example: --project
  "Fabrikam Fiber".
- start-date: Optional. Enter the start date of the    iteration path.
  Example: "2019-06-03". Must be earlier than the    finish-date.

For details ,please refer to this official document: [Add iterations and set iteration dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-devops-cli#add-iterations-and-set-iteration-dates)